# Angular 4 error: Template parse errors: Unexpected translation for attribute "label"

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

After some refactoring (I splitted a module in two and I updated node_modules to the latest), the app fails to launch. I re-generated the translation file `messages.en.xlf` and copied it in `src/locale`. This is the error message I get in console.

@angular 4.1.1 -> 4.2.6

```
compiler.es5.js:1689 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected translation for attribute "label" (id="05ed0716e6b17b25acb25b15efbf6c885bc2ba49") ("
<div class="content slim-scrollbar visible-scrollbar">

    [ERROR ->]<card-cmp class="cerulean-blue-label col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 clearfix"
            i18n-label label="<b"): ng:///PortfoliosModule/PortfolioCompositionCmp.html@6:1
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1689)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeLoadedTemplate (compiler.es5.js:14120)
    at compiler.es5.js:14106
    at Object.then (compiler.es5.js:1679)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateOnly (compiler.es5.js:14106)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplate (compiler.es5.js:14088)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15117)
    at compiler.es5.js:26692
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at compiler.es5.js:26691
```

Faulty template code (previously working just fine):

```
<card-cmp class="cerulean-blue-label col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 clearfix"
    i18n-label label="<b>Composition</b>"
    [hasCollapse]="false">
    //...
</card-cmp>
```

**Edit:**

Looks like downgrading the libs back to the previous setup prevents the error from occurring.

Comment: Had this problem a second time, looked for a the same issue again. Found this question with a similar problem, yay! Actually it was me 6 months earlier :))